# How to remove the beginning slash from req.uri in haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I need to extra the `req.uri` from a request in my frontend in haproxy. Here is what my haproxy looks like

```
frontend fe_ingress

   ...

  http-request set-var(req.uri) path   
  http-request add-header endpoint %[var(req.uri)]
```

so I need to extract the `req.uri` and add it as a header to the subsequent request. Right now, it has `/` in its beginning but I need to remove the first `/`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`regsub` filter](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.1/configuration.html#7.3.1-regsub) to modify the value with a regular expression search-and-replace when setting the header. This can look like this:

```
http-request add-header endpoint %[path,regsub(^/,)]
```